# Why is 有 used in 你的表有一点儿快?

Tags: grammar, usage

I have the following sentence:

> 你的表有一点儿快。

I understand this sentence to have the meaning in English of "Your watch is a little bit fast." But if I were put this sentence into Chinese, I would say "你的表很快"， or "你的表一点儿快". Why is there 有 the first sentence, and what is its meaning/grammatical purpose?

Comment: '快' in the context of watch generally means the watch is showing some time point **after** the current time. It represents the status, not the speed, so ‘你的表很快’ is not a correct usage. I would say '你的表快了' or '你的表快了很多'.

Answer (score 3):

你的表 (your watch) is the topic

有一点儿快 ( is a little bit fast) is the comment

in '有一点儿快',  '有' (having) indicates 'possession' of a condiction or ability, which is 'being faster than normal'

therefore, the literal translation of the sentence would be 'your watch is having a problem of being a little bit faster than normal'

[(topic) + (comment)] sentence structure is different from typical S+V+O structure like "你的表(subject) 行(verb) 快了 (adverb)"

Since 你的表有一点儿快 is a [(topic) + (comment)] structure, '一点儿快' describes something the watch possesses, therefore you need '有' to indicate this possession

Comment: You're probably right. If that is changed then, what is the purpose of the 有 in the sentence?

Comment: Would it be proper to also say 你的表很快 or 你的表一点而快?

Comment: since adjectives function as predicates (w/o any verb e.g. 是）你的表（一点儿）快 also is grammatical,cf. 表快两分钟,他精神不快,此马虽快, 然力薄不堪苦行。 --《晋书·王湛传》动作快 it seems in the meaning (timepiece) is fast, 他的表快（了）would be possible (w/o 很，see dictionaries)）degree adverb 很 usually used with gradable adjectives, in the sense of "gaining time" however "fast" is usually used in an ungradable meaning (like dead), therefore no 很

Comment: correction of comment #3: 你的表一点儿快 in fact seems not to exist (see answer), more generally 一点（儿）＋ 形 does not exist, 一点（儿）＋ NP (e.g. 事情、意思）does exist, also negative 一点（儿）也不＋形 does exist，e.g.一点儿也不错 (besides 一点儿也没错）

Answer (score 2):

I think you can consider 有一点儿 and 一点儿 as different phrases, because their usage are different.

有一点儿, meaning '**a bit**', is put **before** the word that it modifies. As in your example: 你的表有一点儿快. Another example is: 这问题有一点儿难（this question is a bit hard）.

一点儿 is put **after** the word as a complement, denoting **'extent' or 'degree' enhanced a bit**. For example: 把题目出得难一点儿. (Make the questions a bit harder).

Compare 有一点儿难 and 难一点儿: 有一点儿难 describe that '**something is being a bit hard to deal with**'; 难一点儿 is used to describe '**to increase the degree of difficulty a bit**'

Your sentence 你的表有一点儿快 means *the time indicated by your watch is a bit ahead to the actual time*. Say your watch shows it's 6:15, but the actual time is 6:00.  If you want to use 一点儿, you might have to put it after 快: 快一点儿. 一点儿快 doesn't make sense in any case I can think of. Well, 快一点儿 means "**go faster a bit**" or just "**go faster**", which is quite different from 有一点儿快. So, 快一点儿 doesn't fit for your sentence, because it means differently.

Note: there is another uasage of 一点儿. It can be used to **emphasize the negative**. For example, 你说的一点都没错！meaning you are absolutely right(without even a subtle mistake). This usage is different from what you are asking.

Hope this could help you out.